# Соблюдение PSR-1. Побочные эффекты и знаки. Как соблюсти при Композиции?

Tags: php, рефакторинг, стандарт

Разбираюсь со стандартом PSR-1.

Пункт 3 гласит:
*Файлам СЛЕДУЕТ либо объявлять знаки (классы, функции, константы, и т.д.) или оказывать побочный эффект (например, генерировать вывод, изменять .ini настройки, и т.д.) но НЕ СЛЕДУЕТ делать и то и другое.*

По логике получается если я объявил класс `SuperClass` в файле `superclass.php`, в этом же файле я не могу выполнить `require_once` другого файла.

Как быть в той ситуации, когда у меня есть набор файлов с классами-helper'ами(например - хэширование, генерирование имени пользователя, генерирование графиков...), которые используются в классе `SuperClass`?


**Как я бы сделал**:


**Первый вариант**: могу подключить helper'ы в родительском файле, который использует `SuperClass`. Но тогда это будет нарушением принципа Open-Close. Так как клиент должен будет знать о реализации класса, который он использует.

**Второй вариант** - я могу использовать Dependency Injection и передавать в SuperClass нужные ему helper'ы. Но их ОЧЕНЬ много. Будет конструктор-монстр или очень долгий шаблон Builder, что тоже не всегда хорошо.


Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой вариант лучше и есть ли еще варианты?

Не использовать PSR-1 НЕ могу - требование менеджера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PSR-1` предполагает использование механизма [autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), в частности соответствующего `PSR-4` (либо устаревшего `PSR-0`).

И всё, никакого противоречия в требованиях, никаких странных архитектурных граблей, как и вовсе нет множества раскиданных всюду `include`. В файле с объявлением класса остаётся только объявление этого класса. Все другие классы, используемые в этом файле, будут подгружены из своих файлов автоматически по вполне понятным путям из названия и пространства имён требуемого класса.

---

Впрочем, я бы не сказал, что `include_once` или `require_once` объявления чего-либо другого нарушает требование PSR-1, что файл должен или объявлять что-то или выполнять `side-effects`.

Comment: Вопрос - если autoloading инженерами на проекте был признан оверхэд? В этом случае как? И где в PSR-1 информация, что он 'предполагает' autoloading? И если это действительно так - получается PSR-1 автоматом тянет за собой соблюдение PSR-4. Правильно понимаю?

Comment: "Впрочем, я бы не сказал, что include_once или require_once объявления чего-либо другого нарушает требование PSR-1, что файл должен или объявлять что-то или выполнять side-effects" - об этом написано в стандарте. Ты либо объявляешь, либо выполняешь side-effects. require или require_once относится к side-effects. В любом случае - спасибо за ответ. Сейчас хотя бы намеки на ясность где искать дальше.

Comment: PSR-1 практически начинается с этого: `Namespaces and classes MUST follow an “autoloading” PSR`. Насчёт side effects да, я не прав оказался, `explicit use of require` там явно оговорено как side effect.

Comment: Спасибо за autoload! Как PHP все-таки круто!!!!! Надеюсь больше его использовать в реальных проектах